# Bootstrap4 grid system align cols to be close to each other

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col m-2">
            <div />
        </div>
        <div class="col m-2">
            <div />
        </div>
        <div class="col m-2">
            <div />
        </div>
...
    </div>
</div>
```

So in this width it looks well aligned
[image: equals...]

When i go slightly wide i see that the div's in the second row are not close to each other. Is there a way to align the cols in the last column to be close to each other (and aligned with column 2,3,4 of row 1)?
[image: slightly wide]

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/41735/) for the same.

Comment: Just added a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`col-auto`** instead of ***`col`**, because you use fixed width for the `boxes` so that they takes as much space as necessary. And use **`justify-content-center`** for the row to  align the columns in the center. Most importantly, use **`p-2`** instead of **`m-2`**.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-auto p-2">
      <div class="box mx-auto">
         hello
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto p-2">
      <div class="box mx-auto">
         hello
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto p-2">
      <div class="box mx-auto">
         hello
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto  p-2">
      <div class="box mx-auto">
         hello
      </div>
   </div>   
   <div class="col-auto p-2" >
      <div class="box mx-auto">
         hello
      </div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6bx12u5w

---

You use an older version of Bootstrap. Better to use the latest one since there are a few new classes has been added.

---

## Update

**`col`** takes all the available space while **`col-auto`** takes as much as space as it needs: it takes as much space as the natural width of it content.

Comment: What exactly is col-auto doing, as opposed to just col?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different options for last row alignment.

**Align last row to center**

I see that you want the last row cols aligned under 2,3,4, so in this case you can simply use `justify-content-center` along with the `col-auto` columns. The `col-auto` uses flexbox shrink to make the column width fit the content.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto m-2">
            <div class="box mx-auto">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto m-2">
            <div class="box mx-auto">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
        ..
        <div class="col-auto m-2">
            <div class="box mx-auto">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto m-2">
            <div class="box mx-auto">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/iwL7PW77En

---

**Align last row to left**

Aligning the last row to the left is a flexbox issue that has been addressed before. If you don't mind having the entire layout not centered, just use col-auto to shrink the width of the columns to fit the boxes and justify-content-start.

```
<div class="row no-gutters justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-auto m-2">
            <div class="box mx-auto">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto m-2">
            <div class="box mx-auto">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
        ....
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/LZkOF9zexh (align start)

If you need the **entire layout centered**, as you can see from the other answers there are various workarounds to align the last row left. IMO, the simplest, most reliable way in Bootstrap 4 is using a empty spacer elements at the end. You'll need 4 empty spacers since the max in any row is 5 cols.

```
<div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto m-2">
        <div class="box mx-auto">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto m-2">
        <div class="box mx-auto">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto m-2">
        <div class="box mx-auto">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="col-auto m-2">
        <div class="box mx-auto">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto m-2">
        <div class="box invisible"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto m-2">
        <div class="box invisible"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto m-2">
        <div class="box invisible"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto m-2">
        <div class="box invisible"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/F7pGyqIIT6 (spacers at end)